# Yubikey with Kleopatra on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, yubikey

I have a Yubikey 4C Nano that I use with Linux and MacOS without issue. Recently, I installed a version of Windows on my macbook pro that allows me to dual-boot (so I can run the windows version of our application).

I installed the necessary requirements for Yubikey to use through git, namely GPG4Win. After rebooting, if I launch Kleopatra, select Tools -> Manage Smartcards, it doesn't show an entry for my smart card until I hit F5 to refresh.

If I don't perform this process of refreshing, my key also is not recognized in gitbash. BUT, once I perform this step, it *is* recognized and I can use it for the rest of the session.

My question is whether there is a way to script this so that I don't have to do this manual process every time I boot into Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that `cmd.exe` and `msys` were actually using two different versions of gpg.

From msys:

```
$ gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.18-unknown
libgcrypt 1.8.5
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: /c/Users/scottj/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

From within `cmd.exe`:

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.17
libgcrypt 1.8.4
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: C:/Users/scottj/AppData/Roaming/gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Aside from not starting the `gpg-agent`, I was also unable to run `gpg --card-status` from within msys and get any output.

To fix this issue, I went into `/usr/bin` within msys and removed these files:

```
gpg.exe
gpg-connect-agent.exe
gpg-agent.exe
gpgconf.exe
gpg-error.exe
gpgparsemail.exe
gpgscm.exe
gpg-sm.exe
gpgtar.exe
gpgv.exe
gpg-wks-server.exe
```

(Or, more accurately, moving them to another location so you don't lose them, in the event that this backfires)

After doing this, `gpg --card-status` works within msys/Git Bash.